# SQL Server Repeatedly using of deleted identity PK

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Just a general question.
I have a table with IDENTITY PK which is not connected with any table through.
There is another and only FK in the table.

I run DELETE command on that table by some condition.

I can INSERT any new records into the table with auto-inserted next PK IDs.

BUT there is no re-using of ID numbers in PK.

If I run something like

```
DECLARE @max_PKid BIGINT;
SET @max_PKid = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(PKid), 0) FROM Table WHERE FKid=@somevalue);
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Table', reseed, @max_PKid)
```

right after DELETE, there will be access violation problems on next INSERT

Question 1: Is it good practice in general having intervals in unordered (say, unseeded) PKids in the table after doing DELETE/INSERT without using DBCC CHECKIDENT? Should I care on them?

Question 2: If not, what can I do about?

Comment: Why does it matter if there are gaps in your identity field? It's just a surrogate key and shouldn't have any inherit meaning. If you go about this, your app will likely have major concurrency problems as it grows. If you *must* manage identity values yourself, don't use an identity.

Comment: Ok, I got the idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you should not worry. There are also other circumstances in which you can get a 'hole' in an IDENTITY range. For example, if you start a transaction, insert 100,000 rows into a table, then rollback that transaction - those IDENTITY values are then gone. This is not something you should be concerned about.